# QR Code for launching a native application

Tags: android, qr-code

2 questions about using a QR code in an Android device:
1. Is it possible to launch a native Android application from a QR code? Maybe by some configured URI schema?
2. Another option which might be useful for me is to have a QR code scanner inside my own app. Will it be possible for me to somehow include a different app that scans QR codes inside my app? Or will I have to implement the scanning myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

To scan barcodes in Android by Intent, see https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent

To trigger an app from a QR code, yes, you need to register the app to handle the particular custom URL scheme. This is how the same app can respond to clicks on the web: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages

Look at how it registers to handle URLs here: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Sean Owen it directs me to download the scanner app

Answer (score 1):

1.to use a configured schema you can check this post

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Then the you could QR code this scheme just like market://
2. You could use [Bar code scanner app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en) and use below code to launch or you could even integrate the zxing library to scan yourself.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
   intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
   intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE",
            "ONE_D_MODE,QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE,DATA_MATRIX_MODE");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```