# Make QR Code to Open Android Application?

Tags: qr-code

How to make QR Code to open android application?
because I just to know, make QR code for open URL or Website

example :
I have android application, there is Ticket Order of Theater Movie,  where if I scan QR
Code at Poster from my smartphone, this application will open
automatically, according to the movie which I scan.

Please answer my question, because this is my problem to make final project.

Comment: There is already an answer for this on stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773687/qr-code-for-launching-a-native-application