# Scan QR code to open android app

Tags: android, qr-code

I've read several q/a's about how to link a qr code to a custom android application, but I would like to know if it is possible to (and if so how to) make a qr code launch any android application, like games, tools, etc.

Comment: google: "qr code open app":  i feel lucky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773687/qr-code-for-launching-a-native-application

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but what about launching an app that I didn't make?

Comment: you can put the app store reference and launch to his page. About launching the app directly dont know...