# Is there a way to embed logic in a QR code?

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

I have a requirement where I need to generate a QR code which, when scanned, displays the following behaviour.

1. When scanned for the first time, if my ios/android app is not installed then it takes the user to the appstore to prompt them to install the app.
2. When scanned again, if the app is already installed then it should open the app to a particular screen in the app.

Is it possible to create a QR code (or is it the app?) that behaves like this?

Comment: not the qr code itself will behave like this but the website the QR code ALWAYS redirects to has to implement that exact logic.

Comment: it's the app that will behave differently, not the QR itself.

Comment: use firebase dynamic links to create a url and use this url for qr code

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is not be implemented in QR code. This will be implemented in your app.

I talk about Android. Same will be for iOS.

- QR code will give you applicationId. (like `com.stackexchange.marvin`)
- Get list of installed apps. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2695746/6891563) for getting installed apps list.

  - If user has installed this package name already, then open the app. See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422758/6891563)
  - If not installed then [open play store page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11753000/6891563).

Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778268/6891563